# Vue 3 reactivity differences Provide/Inject vs this.$slots.default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity, primevue

currently I am working on a [PR to the primefaces/primevue](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/pull/4767) repository, which will provide the ability to wrap Column components in custom components for the [DataTable](https://primevue.org/datatable/).
As you can see in the PR (see the previous link) I added a way for Column components to register themselves with the parent DataTable by using the [Provide/Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) funcitonality, instead of relying on `this.$slots.default` to find child Column components like it is [currently done in DataTable](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/components/lib/datatable/DataTable.vue#L1847).

But I found one issue. When a property of my wrapper Column changes, the rendered DataTable doesn't reflect that. After digging deeper I noticed, that `this.$.vnode` seems to loose it's reactivity [when it registers itself with the DataTable](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/pull/4767/commits/44e024394f393398f6d7ad17bbad6f9e9dc0a330#diff-fe5d34557eb20045644ab7482b66851589644992135ec7fd8e8101a55f6e2f98R10).

I could reproduce this with a small example in the Vue 3 Playground [HERE](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). Click on the button and you will see, that the change in the Child component value prop is only picked up, when it is accessed through `this.$slots.default`. I also tried making the `registeredChildren` array explicitly reactive by using the following in Parent.vue:

```
setup(){
  const registeredChildren = reactive([])
  return {registeredChildren}
}
```

My question is: What are the differences between accessing a vnode by using `this.$slots.default` and by saving the vnode in an array? How can I make sure, that changes in the vndoe are reflected, by using Provide/Inject?

Any and all help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, shortly after posting the question I randomly tried using `this.$` instead of `this.$.vnode` and now it works.

So the answer to the question is: **There is no difference, if you pass in the correct value.**

I updated the [playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: Accept this to mark it as the correct answer.