# How to pass reactive vnode to injected function inside component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity, primevue

This is kind of a followup to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459303/vue-3-reactivity-differences-provide-inject-vs-this-slots-default/77459344). Basically I try to register a vnode with a parent through an injected function. The solution in the question works (it retains reactivity, but a different problem is created by that. Since `this.$` is the component instance and not the vnode (which is `this.$.vnode`), components trying to access the registered objects children (f.e. slots) via `vnode.children` will not have access to them.

I created an example [HERE](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) to show what I mean.

Looking deeper into it, using `this.$.vnode.children` also doesn't seem to be the same as the children we get from entries in `this.slots.default()`, which is strange. I would expect the slot to return the same vnode as the component instance has. Why isn't this the case?

Since this is for a PR towards [PrimeVue](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/pull/4767) I am trying to keep the changes to the codebase minimal and backward compatible, so I don't want to change the code that is accessing the `children` prop to something more clean like slots. Many components in the DataTable use this access.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

After some hours experimenting, I found a solution which seems a bit dirty, but does the trick. Since the codebase of PrimeVue needs access to a `children` field, which contains the slots, I simply constructed a Proxy and added this field on registration like this:

```
  // Child.vue
  ...
  mounted() {
    if (this.registerChild && typeof this.registerChild === "function") {
      this.$.children = new Proxy(this.$.slots, {}) // This does the trick
      this.registerChild(this.$)
    }
  }
  ...
```

Full example [HERE](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

The change was introduced to the [PrimeVue PR](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/pull/4767/files/14977546e3d4dc7690796c069fc567065b6907f2#diff-fe5d34557eb20045644ab7482b66851589644992135ec7fd8e8101a55f6e2f98R10).

If you know of any cleaner way, I'd be happy to hear it! :D